# Error including sysc directory using SystemC and Cmake Linux

Tags: c++, libraries, systemc

I was trying to use a library from sysc using Cmakelists.txt but it doesn't find it, the systemc.h works flawlesly. Any help?
This is my Cmakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(Practica3_CHS)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD ${SystemC_CXX_STANDARD})

add_executable(Practica3_CHS secuencia.cpp secuencia.h practicaFSM_Secuencia.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Practica3_CHS systemc)
```

And this is the sample of code

```
#include "systemc.h"
#include <sysc/tracing/sc_vcd_trace.h>
```

I tried using the find_required_package(CLanguage ....) but it doesn´t work. Note that im using linux and the systemc library is in /usr/lib/sysc/... Thanks in advance.
This is the exact error

```
fatal error: sysc/tracing/sc_vcd_trace.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include <sysc/tracing/sc_vcd_trace.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what the error actually was and where you installed that library and if you can even use `find_required_package`

Comment: yeah sure i just edited the post

Comment: Is it not finding a library or a header.  Those are different.  You also didn't include anything I asked for.  "the default library path of Ubuntu" is ambiguous.  You should include *the exact error message* not just some comment "this library isn't found" on a header

Comment: ok ok sorry, I dont know where is exactly installed

Comment: "I dont know where is exactly installed " `find / -name "sc_vcd_trace.h" 2>  /dev/null` to find it

Comment: It's in /usr/lib/sysc/tracing/sc_vcd_trace.h it says

Comment: @PabloRey, one does not need to include the `sysc/tracing/sc_vcd_trace.h` header file. All the API related to tracing are available in the `sc_core` namespace.